# Mysql:Only database name showing up with no tables

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySql, I have around 7 databases and 3-4 tables in each database.  Just from yesterday, my system is showing only database names. It is not showing any table in it. Can anyone tell what has happened and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you see them from command line sql?

Comment: What have you done? What have you tried? What is the error message you're getting? What have you researched? Can you still access PhpMyAdmin and view DB's for example? What system are you using? Why are you asking this on SO and not [Superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: @ some hacked our server and deleted all the tables. poor me!! closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Restore from backup if tables have been dropped.

Comment: I have not dropped the tables!! And, surprisingly tables are not showing up in all the 7 databases. is this can happen because of some linking issue. Anyways please can you tel me, How can I backup the data.